# Is there any reason for not implementing the fastrender package for Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've been investigating ways to make my Meteor app load faster and so I installed the FastRender package (https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-fast-render.html) and I couldn't believe how quick my Meteor app loads now. It's also rather trivial to add in.

I'm just wondering why this package is not just added by default and work implicitly (instead of having to go fastRender:true, it would be true by default and you would have to go fastRender:false to turn it off). Is there any disadvantage to having this package or any use case where I would not want to turn fastRender on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the fast render page, especially the section ["Fast Render exposes some security issues that are not normally issues with Meteor. The following section describes what they are and **how to prevent them**. Some of the issues have been already fixed."](https://meteorhacks.com/fast-render-internals-and-how-it-works.html). Fast render is not maintained by the meteor core team, hence it will not be (as of now) a pre-bundled component to the meteor stack